# Segmentation fault and dynamic memory handling

Tags: c++, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

Ok, two questions.
first of all

**Q1.** I allocated sufficient memory at run time, still after running case 6 two times in a row, the `s1` prints garbage, and on running case 6 for a third time the value of `s1` disappeared

[the first image shows the garbage value at the end of string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7bfl.jpg)

[the second image shows the string 1 has disappeared][2]

**Q2.** the `STCPY( COPY FUCTION)` is not working properly, its showing `segmentation fault`, but again, I reallocated sufficient memory.( I need to copy `s2` to `s1`, so I reallocated `L2(string 2's length)` to `s1` so that there won't be memory wastage)

[segmentation fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qguf5.jpg)

**here's the code:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int STRLEN(char* S){
int i=0;
while(S[i] != '\0'){
    i++;
}
return i;
}

int SUBSTR(char* str1, char* str2){
    //string str1;
    //string str2;
    int L1=0,L2=0;
int i,j,flag=0;
int count=0;
            /*cout<<"\nEnter main string greater characters(str1) : ";
            cin>>str1;

            cout<<"\nEnter phrase to find (str2) : ";
            cin>>str2;
            */
            L1 = STRLEN(str1); //calculate legth of strings
            L2 = STRLEN(str2);
            for(i=0;i<L1;i++){
                count = 0;
                flag = 0;
                for(j=0;j<L2;j+=1){
                    if(str1[i]==str2[j])
                    {
                        //good
                        if(j==L2) //successful phrase's each character 
traversed
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        i++;
                        count++;
                        //j++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                } //terminate inner for loops
                {
                    i -= count; //i was incremented explicitly in 
inner loop. for normal operation,
                }               // i has to be decremented by equal 
no. of increments in inner loop
                if(j==L2) //flag for successful traversing of phrase 2 
in string 1
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }

            }

            if(flag == 1)
            {
                cout<<"\nSUBTRING PRESENT AT "<<(i+1);
            }
return 0;
}

int STREQL(char* str1, char* str2){
    int flag = 0;
    int L1=0,L2=0;
int i,j;
int count=0;
                      /*  cout<<"\nEnter first word  : ";
            cin>>str1;

            cout<<"\nEnter second word : ";
            cin>>str2;*/
        char* p1;
        char* p2;

    p1 = str1;
        p2 = str2;
        while(*(p1) != '\0')
        {
            if(*(p1) == *(p2))
            {
             //good
             p1++;
             p2++;
            }
            else{
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 1 )
        {
            cout<<"\n STRINGS ARE NOT EQUAL";
        }
        else{
            cout<<"\n STRINGS ARE EQUAL";
        }

return 0;
}

int STCPY(char* s1, char* s2){

    int L2 = STRLEN(s2);
    int L1 = STRLEN(s1);
cout<<"\nPASS 1";
        char* s3 = (char*)realloc(s1,L2); //Note :- s3 and s1 point to 
same memory location
cout<<"\nPASS 2";
        while(s2 != '\0')
        {
        *s3 = *s2;
        s3++;
        s2++;
        }
cout<<"\nPASS 3";
s3 -= L2;
s2 -= L2;


cout<<"\n STRING 1 = "<<s1;
cout<<"\n STRING 2 = "<<s2;
return 0;
}

int STRREV(){
return 0;
}

int STRLEN(char* str1, char* str2){
    int L1=0,L2=0;

    L1=STRLEN(str1);
    L2=STRLEN(str2);
    cout<<"\nSTRING 1 LENGTH = "<<L1;
    cout<<"\nSTRING 2 LENGTH = "<<L2;
return 0;
}

int STRCAT(char* s1, char* s2)
{
    int L1=0,L2=0;
    int i,j;

    L1=STRLEN(s1);
    L2=STRLEN(s2);  
    //cout<<"\nSTRING 1 LENGTH = "<<L1;
    //cout<<"\nSTRING 2 LENGTH = "<<L2;

    char* s3 = (char*)realloc(s1,(L1+L2));

int cnt=0;
for(i=L1,s3 = s3+L1; *s2 != '\0'; i++)
{
*s3 = *s2;
s2++;
s3++;
 cnt++;
}
s3 = s3-cnt-L1;
s2 = s2-cnt;
//cout<<"\nConcatenated string s3 =  "<<s3;
//cout<<"\nConcatenated string s1 =  "<<s1;

    cout<<"\nSTRING 1 = "<<s1;
    cout<<"\nSTRING 2 = "<<s2;
return 0;
}

int main(){

int i,j,choice;
char* s1;
char* s2;
cout<<"\nEnter string : ";
s1 = (char*)malloc(50);// ok i made this 50 bytes instead of 10
cin.getline(s1,50);    // cause u guys arguing, but still that doesn't change the output
//cout<<s1;

cout<<"\nEnter string : ";
s2 = (char*)malloc(50);
cin.getline(s2,50);
//cout<<s2;

cout<<"\n------------MENU------------";
cout<<"\n1.SUBSTRING FIND";
cout<<"\n2.EQUAL CHECK";
cout<<"\n3.COPY STRING";
cout<<"\n4.REVERSE";
cout<<"\n5.STRING LENGTH";
cout<<"\n6.STRING CONCATENATION";
cout<<"\n7.EXIT";
cout<<"\n----------------------------";
do{
cout<<"\n\nEnter your choice : ";
cin>>choice;


    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        SUBSTR(s1, s2);    
        break;
    case 2:
            STREQL(s1, s2); 
        break;
    case 3:
        STCPY(s1, s2);
        break;
    case 4:
        STRREV();
        break;
    case 5:
        STRLEN(s1, s2);
        break;
    case 6:
        STRCAT(s1, s2);
        break;
    case 7:
        break;
    }
}while(choice != 7);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Segmentation fault = Time to open that debugger and find out why.

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line  with the debugger?

Comment: Is there any reason to re-write fundamentals like `substr` and `strlen`? I'm hoping this is an academic exercise. If so, it's doubly odd that this is tagged as C++ since this is basically C code apart from the use of `cout`. It's also worth mentioning that function names are generally lower or mixed case in C/C++ where `ALL_CAPS` is by convention a hint that you're using a macro.

Comment: Use `std::string` and leave the memory management to the implementation.  As you can see this is really easy to mess up when first learning the language.

Comment: well for a start you malloc 10 chars and try to read in 50

Comment: @tadman i know this is basic C code, but i want to do this in c++ that too without using predefined methods. I'm actually trying to understand logic behind dynamic memory handling in char array/ pointers/ strings.

Comment: next, strcat doesnt zero terminate its output

Comment: @NathanOliver, i don't want readymade stuff, i want to recreate the logic behind dynamic memory handling in strings without using predefined methods

Comment: You'll want to become hyper-aware of code that makes use of uninitialized variables, that's the biggest source of problems like this. Additionally, instead of your quirky menu-driven tests, use a proper unit testing library like [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) to verify your methods are working completely as expected by exposing them to a variety of carefully constructed use cases. You have tons of code here with zero automated tests, so you may as well be flying blind.

Comment: @pm100,doesn't matter, I'm taking care that i enter below 10, also if you see, I've reallocated sufficient memory for string concatenation and reduced again sufficiently for string copy

Comment: You've allocated room for 10 bytes, but are accepting 50. That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @pm100,what's up with doesn't zero, i didn't get

Comment: @tadman, even if i change 10 bytes to 50 bytes it still doesnt make any change

Comment: Just because nothing changes doesn't mean it isn't a bug. You may have several things going on at the same time and are only seeing the end results of one malfunction.

Comment: when you create a string you have to add a zero byte on the end

Answer (score 1):

Replace everything under "PASS 2" log to this:

```
    while(*s2 != '\0')
        {
          *s3 = *s2;
          s3++;
          s2++;
        }
```

Observe that s2 != '\0' means basically: s2 != nullptr which is never true. That's why you get segmentation fault.

Comment: that still doesn't work. Still segmentation fault(core dumped)

Comment: also that doesn't make sense, s3 and s2 are pointers not regular variables

Comment: @officialnitish I tested it and works. ++ operator for a pointer means (current+sizeof(type of current)), i.e. point to the next location and reinterpret it as if it was of the same type of (in our case) s2.

Comment: @officialnitish if it doesnt make sense then how come you did what he is suggesting in your `STRCAT` method?  not to mention `*s2` is giving you the value, and the comparison of a char to char instead of a char* to a char.

Answer (score 0):

A C string is ended with a final \0. So the memory footprint is strlen(str) + 1 byte. 
The problem with your STRCAT function is that you forgot to add space for the final \0 (s3 = realloc(s1, L1+L2 **+1**), and you also forgot to add the final \0 (s3[L1+L2] = 0).
idem for your STCPY function, + s2 != 0 to replace with *s2 != 0